# action import in Redux

Tags: javascript, redux

I have a lot of actions in my Redux and I want to create special list with actions' names, because strings ara hard to find. I read about such possibility. So, I have some problems with import.
In my actions' list I have

```
export const updatePrice = (price) => {
  return {
    type: "updatePrice",
    payload: { price },
  };
};
```

On special list actionType

```
export const updatePrice = "updatePrice";
```

And in component

```
import { updatePrice } from "../actions/actionType";
```

How should I import from actionType to the component.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Is there any error?

Comment: I think we dont need the second export, we already export the function on the declaration section.  is that your issue?

Comment: Thanks all. There were not any error, I tried to refactor it.